# List updating when shouldnt?

Tags: list, each, updating

I am using a static class in my application.  It basically uses an access database, and copies itself to various lists.

When the user modifies some data, the data is updates in the list, using LINQ, if there is no entry in the list for the modification then it will add a new item to the list.

This all works fine.

However on the 1st data interrogation, I create the original list, basically all records in the users table, so I have a list `lstDATABASERECORDS`.

What I do after populating this list I do `lstDATABASERECORDSCOMPARISON=lstDATABASERECORDS`

this enables me to quickly check whether to use an update or append query.

However when I add to `lstDATABASERECORDS` a record is added in `lstDATABASERECORDSCOMPARISON` too.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: so, you might want to tag the .Net languages you're using on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning two variables to refer to the same instance of a list. Instead, you may want to try generating a clone of your list to keep for deltas (`ICloneable` is unfortunately not that useful without additional work to define cloneable semantics for your objects), or use objects that implement `IEditableObject` and probably `INotifyPropertyChanged` for change tracking (there's a few options there, including rolling your own).

There's nothing built in to the framework (until EF) that replicates the old ADO recordset capability to auto-magically generate update queries that only attempt to modify changed columns.

Comment: Many thanks, apologies, i wrote this before starting to delve into the duplicates/pointers.

Comment: If there's further help you need, feel free to edit your question to add more information.